# 2D освещение в юнити 2D

Tags: unity3d

проблема:
у меня в 2D игре используются Point Light и спрайты с шейдером sprites/diffuse.
когда Point Light 1 или 2 все норм , но если их больше то у некоторых как будто падает интенсивность .
**как сделать чтобы при большом количестве Point Light не падала интенсивность у каждого ?**

[image: 1]

вот пример .
я поставил всего лишь 9 Point Light а уже они разные.
настройки у них стандартные , только цвет с белого на оранжевый поменял и все .
**как решить проблему их различия ?**

Comment: уже не надо . я нашёл в чем беда была

Comment: Ну так напишите, не будьте таким скрытным )

Comment: Render mode поменял на important и все заработало

Answer (score 0):

> Render mode поменял на important и все заработало

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/546606)

Comment: @AlexSazonov к сожалению, это ответ